# Validate that connection string is for Sql Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

How validate that a connection string entering by a user is for Sql Server 2008? I'm using C#.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to verify the *version*? Or the product? You can't verify the version from the connection string - the same string will work for many versions of SQL Server

Comment: http://alexpinsker.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/regular-expressions-for-connection.html

Comment: That is a good question!

Comment: Here is code you need http://dbaccesstesterclient.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you need to validate or users are entering a connection string but  you can find connections strings for sql 2008 from below link.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

```
Standard Security
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
Use serverName\instanceName as Data Source to connect to a specific SQL Server instance.
Are you using SQL Server 2008 Express? Don't miss the server name syntax Servername\SQLEXPRESS where you substitute Servername with the name of the computer where the SQL Server Express installation resides.

COPY

Standard Security alternative syntax
This connection string produce the same result as the previous one. The reason to include it is to point out that some connection string keywords have many equivalents.
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;

COPY

Trusted Connection
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;

COPY

Trusted Connection alternative syntax
This connection string produce the same result as the previous one. The reason to include it is to point out that some connection string keywords have many equivalents.
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

COPY

Connecting to an SQL Server instance
The syntax of specifying the server instance in the value of the server key is the same for all connection strings for SQL Server.
Server=myServerName\theInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

COPY

Trusted Connection from a CE device
Often a Windows CE device is not authenticated and logged in to a domain. To use SSPI or trusted connection / authentication from a CE device, use this connection string.
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
Note that this will only work on a CE device.
Read more about connecting to SQL Server from CE devices here
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Try to connect to SQL server. On error, it's invalid
2. Use a connectionstring builder ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms254947.aspx ) and just ask the user for the values that are required. Maybe a bit easier for your users

*Edit:* If you want to get the SQL Server's version, you can get it you can use `select @@version` once you're connected. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms254947.aspx for reference. But you first need to connect.

Comment: OP seems to be asking to validate that the connection string is "for" SQL Server 2008; not merely whether it is valid.

Comment: If he want's to get the SQL Server version, no way without connecting to the sql server (updated my answer to show how it would be possible). If connected it's also a proof of validity.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what you're asking. Can you tell us in plain words (not code) how you would determine if a connection string is for SQL Server 2008? Connection strings specify the server name (and instance where appropriate), the database name, credentials, etc. There is nothing in a connection string that specifies what version it is for.

Do you mean you want to verify whether the server is running SQL Server 2008? You can do that once you've successfully connected by issuing:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion');
```

An answer with:

```
  8.0.xxxx.xx = SQL Server 2000
  9.0.xxxx.xx = SQL Server 2005
 10.0.xxxx.xx = SQL Server 2008
10.50.xxxx.xx = SQL Server 2008 R2
 11.0.xxxx.xx = SQL Server 2012
```

If you have earlier versions, good luck with those. :-)

Comment: You forgot SQL Server 6.5! ;) Oh, wait...